# Wxpython. Определить страницу под курсором

Tags: python, wxpython

Использую wxpython для оконного приложения. Есть некий класс - LibPalette, который наследуется от wx.Notebook. Это окно вида

[image: палитра]

Видно две страницы test и controls. Каждая страница это тоже класс. Страницы добавляются с помощью метода AddPage(). Хотелось бы при наведении курсора мыши на вкладку выводить некую подсказку.

Вопрос в следующем: как определить на что наведен курсор мыши?

Можно было бы использовать метод self.GetPageText(self.GetSelection()) и определять по id-шнику страницу, но это работает только для конкретной выбранной страницы. А хотелось бы независимо от той страницы, на который сейчас находимся, выводить данные для той страницы на которую наведен курсор. Возможно это как-то сделать?

Так же, если кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста, как перейти на другую страницу при нажатии на нее ПКМ? Объявил событие self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightClick), но вот никак не получается перейти на другую вкладу (пробовал генерировать событие клика ЛКМ, не помогло).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верное решение, предложенное пользователем ТабуретY.

Первая тема вопроса:

```
mouseCoordinate = event.GetPosition()
sel_item, flags = self.HitTest(mouseCoordinate) # Возвращает индекс вкладки в указанной позиции или NOT_FOUND
objLP = event.GetEventObject() # объект который нас интересует
```

Вторая тема:

```
mouseCoordinate = event.GetPosition()
sel_item, flags = self.HitTest(mouseCoordinate) # Возвращает индекс вкладки в указанной позиции или NOT_FOUND
self.SetSelection(sel_item) # переход на вкладку

page = self.pages[sel_item] # список, который хранит страницы
```